# pybluez install windows 7 64 bits python 3.3

Tags: windows, python-3.x, 64-bit

I have this message Error : Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

when I use "python setup.py install" to install pybluez

with https://github.com/karulis/pybluez under windows 7 64 bits.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic assumption is that you do have Microsoft Visual Studio Express installed (2010, at least) and environment variable `VS100COMNTOOLS` set to proper path in Program Files directory.

I've installed VS 2015 and created mentioned variable with following value: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\`.